# How to create new multiple macros(fixed location) next to a specific column after a macro is run

Tags: excel, nested, vba

I have built a macro that reads invoices which are in text format into excel.

Now, I wish to create invoice which I can later print. I wish to add a command box **next to each invoice number**( say name of command box- view/print invoice #).

Which will direct to a new sheet where I will have my respective invoice number.
Where I can view the invoice and quality check and decide to print or not.

Question- How can I add a new command window next to each invoice number?

The function would take the invoice number next to it and all its details- I can do the coding for it.  I only wish to know how to make a macro build multiple command windows based on a counter(invoice number here) and how to make those respective command windows have a fixed position in the excel-(next to the invoice number)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I can think of two approaches:  .1) You can have a specific macro to loop through the sheet and insert a button in the adjacent column, or .2) you can designate the sheet to insert a button upon change event given the change event happens in a specific range (the column you have your invoice number) meeting specific criteria (="*").

Answer (score 0):

This will add a command button next to each invoice number and link it to a macro named "viewInvoice" where you can add whatever code you need. Hope this is what you're looking for!

```
Option Explicit

Sub addButtons()

Dim x As Variant
Dim lr As Long
Dim bl As Long
Dim bt As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("invoice list") '<<sheet name

    .Columns("D").AutoFit '<<assumes invoice number in column D
    .Columns("E").Insert
    .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 18.56
    .Range("E1").Value = "View Invoice"
    .Range("E1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    .Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).RowHeight = 20 '<<assumes data starts on row 2

    For Each x In Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If x.Value <> "" Then

            bl = x.Offset(0, 1).Left + 2
            bt = x.Top + 2

            .Buttons.Add(bl, bt, 100, 16).Select '(from left, from top, button width, button height), adjust as needed

            With Selection
                .Characters.Text = x.Value
                .OnAction = "viewInvoice"
                .Placement = xlMove 'or xlFreeFloating or xlMoveAndSize
                .PrintObject = False
            End With

        End If

    Next x

.Range("A2").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("invoice list")

End Sub


Sub viewInvoice()

Dim bn As String

bn = Application.Caller

MsgBox "Will display invoice #" & ActiveSheet.Buttons(bn).Text & "!", vbInformation, "View Invoice"

End Sub
```